# if statement is running without the press of submit button in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want my if statement to show insert successful or failed only after I press the submit button, but as soon as I load my function master admin, is shows insert failed. What's wrong in my code.

```
       public function masteradmin(){  
        $data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        $this->load->view('user/layout/header',array('data'=>$data));
        $this->load->view('user/layout/left_navbar',array('data'=>$data));
        $this->load->view('user/appconfig/masteradmin');

        $this->load->view('user/layout/footer');
          $post= $this->input->post();
          unset ($post['submit']);
          $this->load->model('AppconfigModel');

            if ($this->AppconfigModel->insert_masteradmin($post))
            {
                echo "insert successfull";
            }

            else
            {
                echo "insert failed";
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

if `form submit and post have value that time only it will execute`

```
$post= $this->input->post();
if($post){
    unset ($post['submit']);
    $this->load->model('AppconfigModel');

    if ($this->AppconfigModel->insert_masteradmin($post))
    {
      echo "insert successfull";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "insert failed";
    }
}
```